# Solving a particular second order equation

Tags: polynomials, mathematical-physics

The original problem comes from plasma physics but my issue is purely mathematical. I encounter the following function

$$\epsilon (k, \omega) = 1 - \frac 1 2 \left[ \frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega-kv_0)^2} + \frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega+kv_0)^2}\right]$$.

I am aimed at

- Finding the range of $k$ for which $\omega_p$ is imaginary.
- Determining what $k_{max}$ is.
- Determining what $\text{Im}(\omega_{max})$

This is how I am tackling it

- OK, it should be simply about finding $k$ for which $\epsilon(k, \omega) = 0$ yields an imaginary solution. However I have two issues with it: 1) This is not an easy looking second order equation to solve 2) I should get two solutions (at least one of them being potentially imaginary)  and not a "range". How could actually solve it?
- This should be simply about finding for what $k$ values does $\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial k} = 0$ hold, do you agree?
- I am confused with this one; Is this simply about finding the function $\epsilon (k, \omega_{max})$ i.e. $\text{Im}(\omega_{max}) = \epsilon (k, \omega_{max})$?

If you need more context please let me know.

---

**EDIT 0**

$$\frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega-kv_0)^2} + \frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega+kv_0)^2} = 2 \Rightarrow \omega_p^2\left( \frac{\omega^2+2kv_0+k^2v_0^2+\omega^2-2kv_0+k^2v_0^2}{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2} \right) = 2$$

$$2\omega_p^2\left( \frac{(\omega^2+k^2v_0^2)}{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2} \right)=2 \Rightarrow \omega_p^2 = \frac{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2}$$

Since $(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2$ is always positive, $\omega_p$ will be imaginary if $$\omega^2+k^2v_0^2<0 \Rightarrow k^2v_0^2 < -\omega^2 \Rightarrow k < \pm i\frac{\omega}{v_0}$$

So the answer is $k < \pm i\frac{\omega}{v_0}$

---

**EDIT 1**

We can determine what $k_{max}$ is via $\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial k} = 0$

$$\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial k} = \frac{\omega_p^2k}{(\omega-kv_0)^3}-\frac{\omega_p^2k}{(\omega+kv_0)^3} = 0 \Rightarrow \omega_p^2k(\omega+kv_0)^3 - \omega_p^2k(\omega-kv_0)^3 = 0$$

Solving for $k$ yields $k_{max}$

Comment: You have $\,\displaystyle \omega_p^2 = \frac{\left(\epsilon (k, \omega) - 1\right)(\omega^2 - k^2 v_0^2)^2}{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2}\,$, so $\,\omega_p\,$ is imaginary iff the RHS is a real negative number.

Comment: @dxiv, thanks for your reply. Then I guess I should look at the range of $k$ values that make the RHS a -ive number. It is then just about solving $\frac{\left(\epsilon (k, \omega) - 1\right)(\omega^2 - k^2 v_0^2)^2}{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2} < 0$ for $k$ ?

Comment: Basically yes, with the caveat that the RHS must be a real number before it can be negative, and you don't say which/whether quantities involved are real or complex.

Comment: @dxiv I edited my post, do you agree that the answer is $k < \pm i\frac{\omega}{v_0}$? :) If yes, would you like to shed some light on the other two points? Thank you.

Comment: For complex numbers the < sign makes no sense .

Comment: @JD_PM If all of $\,\omega,k,v_0\,$ are real then the last equality gives $\,\omega_p^2 \ge 0\,$, so $\,\omega_p\,$ cannot be imaginary. Otherwise you need to specify which of them are non-real complex, and write down the conditions for the RHS to be a negative real. An inequality such as $\,k \lt \pm i \omega / v_0\,$ makes no sense unless both sides are real numbers, since there is no $\,\lt\,$ order between complex numbers..

Comment: @dxiv I see, thank you. We agree that $\omega_p^2 = \frac{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2}$ is OK. Let's assume that $v_0$ has to stay real and only $\omega, k$ can be non-real complex. It is not clear to me what conditions should we impose on them so that $\omega_p$ becomes complex, given that these appear squared on the RHS. Might you please shed some more light on what are the conditions you had in mind for the RHS to be complex? I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @JD_PM Sorry, but you need to clarify what the question is that you mean to ask. For one thing, is it about $\omega_p$ being "*imaginary*" or "*complex*"? They are not the same thing - in common math parlance "*imaginary*" means on the imaginary axis, while "*complex*" means anywhere in the complex plane, including the real and imaginary axes. Then, if $k$ is non-real it doesn't make sense to speak of a "*range*" or a maximum value $\,k_{max}\,$ since, again, there is no $\,\lt\,$ order between complex numbers.

Comment: @JD_PM As for the conditions, it comes down to evaluating the RHS. If it's a non-negative real, then $\,\omega_p\,$ is real. If it's a negative real, then $\,\omega_p\,$ is imaginary. If it's a non-real complex then $\,\omega_p\,$ is a non-real and non-imaginary complex.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for the clarification, I meant imaginary then. I see, let's impose $\frac{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2}$ to be negative real. Let's assume $v_0$ to be real. Based on your comment I see that $k$ has to be real as well. Then the only non real number is $\omega$ (say, $\omega = i$). Then it follows that the condition we need for the RHS to be negative real is $\omega^2 > k^2 v_0^2$. Is then simply about, given a fixed imaginary $\omega$ and a fixed real $v_0$, finding the (real) k range for which $\omega^2 > k^2 v_0^2$ holds?

Comment: @JD_PM If $\,\omega=iw\,$ is imaginary and the rest are reals, then $\,\omega^2 = -w^2\,$ and the condition for imaginary $\,\omega_p\,$ is $\,-w^2 + k^2v_0^2 < 0\,$ $\,\iff -\left|\frac{w}{v_0}\right| \lt k \lt \left|\frac{w}{v_0}\right|,$

Comment: @dxiv I see. I understand now how to get the range of $k$ for which $\omega_p$ is imaginary. Looking at how to determine $k_{max}$; I added an edit 1: do you agree on the procedure? Finally, I do not really know how to obtain $\text{Im}(\omega_{max})$. Might you please add some light on this one? Thank you.

Comment: @JD_PM You'll have to define $k_{\text{max}}$ first. If it's the maximum $k$ in the range that you just found, then it's simply the higher endpoint of the range. Same goes for $\omega_{\text{max}}$ - you'll have to define what it means in this context, before asking how to determine it.

Comment: @dxiv oh, so no derivative of $\epsilon$ w.r.t. $k$ is needed? (i.e. what I wrote in edit 1 is wrong then? If yes I do not see why...). Regarding $\omega_{max}$; my guess is that we should define it as the maximum omega at which the RHS is imaginary. But that is exaclty what we did for $\omega_p$ so I am confused ... Btw I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @JD_PM If, for example, you get $k \in (-1,1)$ at the first step, then one reasonable guess could be that $k_{max}$ means the upper bound i.e. $k_{max}=1$. But guessing is pointless, and the question cannot be answered lest you define what all those quantities are supposed to mean. Unless and until you do that, I am voting to close the question for lack of clarity.

Comment: @dxiv I will study the theory further and then come back to this question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Some essential setup for the problem seems to be missing, so much so that no reasonable argument can be advanced to answer it.  I looked through the edit history, and from the Comments it seems efforts to clarify the Question have come to an end for now.  Essentially the first equation seems to define a function $\epsilon(k, \omega)$, but on the right hand side appears $\omega_p$ with no explanation.  I'm voting to close pending further clarification, e.g. which variables are known and which are unknown.